# Does the maximum entropy Nash equilibrium with integer payoffs have rational probabilities?

Tags: linear-algebra, game-theory, entropy, nash-equilibrium, rationality-testing

I have a symmetric two-player zero-sum game, represented as an $n \times n$ skew-symmetric payoff matrix $M$. The components of $M$ are all integers. Are the probabilities in the *maximum entropy* Nash equilibrium guaranteed to be rational numbers?

Bonus question: if they are, do you know of an algorithm to compute the maximum entropy Nash equilibrium exactly?